# Django - Url Dispatching - Page Not Found

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

I am very puzzled as to why the URL dispatcher is try to look for an empty path although a url was specified for it? Does it imply that it is unable to find the specified url and therefore trying to find the default.

This happens when I try to POST and HttpResponseRedirect searches for an empty path instead of following the specified path. Assume that the other.

Using Django version: 2.0

Thanks in advance!

main/urls.py (ROOT_URLCONF)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('app/', include('shorterner.urls'))
]
```

shorterner/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('request/', views.RequestView.as_view(), name="request"),
  path('list/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="list")
]
```

shorterner/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import View, generic
from .models import Urls

import requests
import json

from .forms import SubmitUrlForm

class RequestView(View):
  form_class = SubmitUrlForm
  initial = { 'url': ''}
  template_name = "shorterner/request.html"
  context_object_name = 'url'

  def form_valid(self, form):
    return super().form_valid(form)

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      input_url = form.cleaned_data['url']
      short_url = google_url_shorten(input_url)

      print(input_url)
      print(short_url)

      new_url = Urls.create(short_url, input_url)
      new_url.save()

      return HttpResponseRedirect('/app/request/')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

shorterner/templates/shorterner/request.html

```
{% extends 'shorterner/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <form action="/" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Url..." required/>        
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Screenshot of the problem
[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOZ2k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're sending form data to this path `/`. But you've not defined that route in `main/urls.py`.

Comment: Hey thanks! Totally missed out the form action's data path was set to "/", silly me.